# Finding the first Non-repeating Character in the given string, not able to pass a few test cases due to Timeout

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm working on a Problem from *CodeSignal*:

> Given a `String s` consisting of the alphabet only, return the **first
> non-repeated** element. Otherwise, return `'-'`.
>
> *Example:* input -
> `s="abacabad"`, output - `'c'`.

I came up with the following the code. It passes only `16/19` test cases. Is there a way to solve this problem in **O(n)** or **O(1)**?

*My code:*

```
public char solution(String s) {
    ArrayList<Character> hs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (char c:s.toCharArray()) {
        hs.add(c);
    }
    
    for (int j=0; j<s.length(); j++) {
        if ( 1 == Collections.frequency(hs, s.charAt(j))) {
            return s.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    
    return '_';
}
```

Comment: is the input lower case a-z only or A-Z as well?

Comment: @DennisLLopis You convinced that English letters are the only valid characters?

Comment: Yes, it's just the alphabet, 26x2 at most, no need for hash sets or maps.

Comment: @IUSR Talk is cheap. Show the link, where requirements are stated if you have it.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko for CodeSignal and LeetCode, the problems are usually the English alphabet, but sometimes they include capital letters too. I wanted to confirm before I contributed an answer. There is a solution using a frequency array to store the count of each character and then you will iterate the string on the second pass and look up the frequency in the array.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Do I now? The only thing matters is the input domain is pretty limited. Any language has an alphabet so large that the memory requirement dwarfs a `LinkedHashMap<Character, Boolean>`? Also If you want to deal with *characters*, then use code points. This fashion of using a hash map, stream, lambdas for an apparent LC/CodeSignal question really says a lot, ergo I don't think I owe you any link.

Comment: @IUSR You're missing the point. Firstly important the algorithm itself, and there might be plenty of implementations. Performance of the solution based on an array and `HashMap` would almost the same. More over, in the real world development Collections are favored over arrays (they very rarely used, see *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch to learn why). And since there are no constraints listed in the question, I've provided a versatile solution, inventing the requirements isn't a good habit.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Admittedly the phrase "talk is cheap" set me off a bit lol My apologies. I can see you were providing an _industrial grade_ solution, capable of coping with the most scenarios. My impression was that this question was in the context of, _grinding_. If the audience is an Online Judge system, then running speed is crucial (well, at least brag-able); if it's for the interviewers then many aspects can be negotiated, such as whether "alphabet" is English, limited, or not, and sometimes they ask you to not use complex classes provided by the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal possible time complexity for this task is linear **O(n)**, because we need to examine every character in the given string to find out whether a particular character is unique.

Your current solution runs in **O(n^2)** - `Collections.frequency()` iterates over all characters in the string and this iteration and this method is called for every character. That's basically a brute-force implementation.

We can generate a map `Map<Character,Boolean>`, which associates each character with a `boolean` value denoting whether it's repeated or not.

That would allow to avoid iterating over the given string multiple times.

Then we need to iterate over the *key-set* to find the first *non-repeated* character. As the `Map` implementation `LinkedHashMap` is used to ensure that returned non-repeated character would be the first encountered in the given string.

To update the `Map` I've used Java 8 method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects three arguments: a *key*, a *value*, and a function responsible for merging the *old value* and the *new one*.

```
public char solution(String s) {
    Map<Character, Boolean> isNonRepeated = getMap(s);
    
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Boolean> entry: isNonRepeated.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }        
    
    return '_';
}

public Map<Character, Boolean> getMap(String s) {
    Map<Character, Boolean> isNonRepeated = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        isNonRepeated.merge(s.charAt(i), true, (v1, v2) -> false);
    }
    return isNonRepeated;
}
```

In case if you're comfortable with streams, this problem can be addressed in one statement (the algorithm remains the same and time complexity would be linear as well):

```
public char solution(String s) {
    
    return s.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap( // creates intermediate Map<Character, Boolean>
            Function.identity(),   // key
            c -> true,             // value - first occurrence, character is considered to be non-repeated
            (v1, v2) -> false,     // resolving values, character is proved to be a duplicate
            LinkedHashMap::new
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst()
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse('_');
}
```

Comment: I like the T/F version over a frequency count.

Comment: @WJS It's more focused on the goal - determine whether an element is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach using both a `Set` to account for duplicates, and a `Queue` to hold candidates before a possible duplicate is discovered.

- iterate over the list of characters.
- try and add the character to the `seen` set. If not already there,
  also add it to the `candidates` queue.
- else if it has been `"seen"`, try and remove it from the candidates queue.
- By the time this gets done, the head of the queue should contain the  first, non-repeating character.  If the queue is empty, return the default value as no unique character was found.

```
public char solution(String s) {
    Queue<Character> candidates = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (seen.add(c)) {
            candidates.add(c);
        } else  {
            candidates.remove(c);
        }
    }
    return candidates.isEmpty() ? '_' : candidates.peek();
}
```

I have done pretty extensive testing of this and it has yet to fail. It is also comparatively very efficient.  But as can happen, I may have overlooked something.

Comment: Nice solution. I have a couple of propositions. **1.** `candidates.remove(c)` has a cost of **O(n)** time because since an arbitrary element of the Queue needs to be removed and not the first one, it results in overall **O(n^2)** worth case time complexity. The fix to that would be to use a `LinkedHashSet`. **2.** Although traditional index-based loop doesn't look very fancy, `s.toCharArray()` creates a new `char[]`. Accusing characters by index via `charAt()` would be cheaper. [*Example*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/uFW)

Comment: Queue is not the best choice for this task, but despite that, the idea of using `Set `is pretty good. Hence, approving the answer.

Comment: I also tried LinkedHashSet as  `"queue"` but it didn't seem to perform as well.  My testing was rudimentary and did not use JMH.

Comment: That is interesting, because `remove(E)` on a `LinkedHashSet` should perform in **O(1)** and with `LinkedList` - in **O(n)**. I suspect that in the case of an alphabetic string, the several nodes would end up in the same bucket since the hash of a `Character` it's simply it's numeric value. If the string would contain characters with far broader range of hashes, the game would be quite different.

Comment: And as I said above, the Queue isn't actually used here as a Queue. Removing from the middle is not a usual pattern while dealing with this type, because it's not something for what this data structure is meant for. It's rather a task for a List. The common pattern with a Queue, as you know, adding to the end and removing from the front. Spiking of concrete implementation array-backed containers will overdo `LinkedList` at any circumstances. `ArrayDeque` (or a plain `ArrayList` if you change the abstract type) would perform better.

Answer (score 0):

One technique would be a 2 pass solution using a frequency/count array for each character.

```
public static char firstNonRepeatingChar(String s) {
        int[] frequency = new int[26]; // this is O(1) space complexity because alphabet is finite of 26 letters
        
        /* First Pass - Fill our frequency array */
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            frequency[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
        }
        /* Second Pass - Look up our frequency array */
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(frequency[s.charAt(i) - 'a'] == 1) {
                return s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        /* Not Found */
        return '_';
    }
```

This solution is O(2n) -> O(n) and a space complexity of O(1) because we are using a finite set of the English alphabet (26 letters). This wouldn't work in other scenarios for non-English alphabets.